# Access to specific private members from specific class

Tags: c++

I have a class

```
class A
{
.....
private:
    int mem1;
    int mem2;
}
```

I have another class B which need to access only to mem1.

```
class B
{
  ....
}
```

How can I access private member mem1 from only from class B? I don't want to use friend. This means access to all private members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some rearrangement to `class A` (which might not necessarily be acceptable), you can achieve this:

```
class Base
{
    friend class B;
    int mem1;
};

class A : public Base
{
    int mem2;
};
```

This exploits the fact that `friend`ship is not transitive through inheritance.

Then, for `class B`,

```
class B
{
    void foo(A& a)
    {
        int x = a.mem1; // allowed
        int y = a.mem2; // not allowed    
    }
};
```

Comment: Then, I upvote this, because we were working in parallel, and your answer is much more complete.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Of course it is. Thanks for sticking you neck out ;-)

Comment: please, take a look to my answer. It was changed after the comment by VladimirYanakiev

Answer (score 3):

You can write a base class with member mem1 and friend B

```
class Base {
   protected:
   int mem1;
   friend class B;
};

class A: private Base {
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks @VladimirYanakiev. Please, take a look to the selected answer ;)